# Prevent app from seeing installed apps

Tags: applications, adb, 8.1-oreo

Is there any way, through settings or ADB, to prevent an app (that I installed) from knowing what other apps are installed?

Comment: AFAIK no. Not possible. One way is to use XprivacyLua Xposed module to activate this hook for that apo so that it doesn't see other apps

Comment: Also going with no as it might break Android. Android settings for example is an app, the launcher is an app, etc.

Comment: @CmosBattery ok it is a user installed app I don't want knowing what apps I have (nothing overly important either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 13 Tiramisu (API Level 29) Will finally support this.

In the meantime I use multiple Android users or the Island / Knox apps.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#getInstalledApplications(android.content.pm.PackageManager.ApplicationInfoFlags)